# window.scrollTo has no effect

Tags: angular

I am having an animation which enlages a card inside a list. It's basically a "fullscreen" animtion. Anyway, everything works so far. The only missing piece is scrolling the list item to the corrent position.

For this I am getting the y-offset of the host element and call `window.scrollTo()` but it has no effect:

```js
animationDone(event) {
  window.scrollTo(0, this.host.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top);
}
```

So, I am not very well educated on this topic but I do not know which element in the DOM `window` actually represents or how `scrollTo` is managed (if this is delegated to the scrollable `div` of the current page).

Here is a small example of how the page looks like:

```xml
<!-- The scrollable content container -->
<div class="content-container">

   <!-- The list items -->

   <div *ngFor="let element of elements>
      <div [@fullscreenAnimation] (@fullscreenAnimation)="animationDone($event)">
          <list-card [data]="element"></list-card>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do here but you can try this solution
Give an element ID reference in HTML

and in your typescript function do this

```
 document.getElementById('yourHTMLElementID').scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth'
     })
```